# Opening and reading pixel values from bitmap images in Modelsim

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, imageprocessing

How do I open a bitmap image, read the pixel data (24 bits) and store it in a memory that I created in a Verilog module in ModelSim?

How do I open the below image in Modelsim? Is it possible in the first place?

If yes, how should I read the pixel data and store it in a 2d-array(memory) that I created as part of the Verilog module?

I have a bitmap image of checker-box.[image]

Comment: Only for simulation ? Then google file operations commands in verilog.

Comment: The end result would be opening another file, constructing the header for the bitmap and then placing this data that I read from this bitmap file in that new file created.

Comment: I used readmemh to open a normal txt file which contains hex data and readmemb to open a txt file that contains binary data. But using these functions, I am not able to read a .bmp file, could you tell how to do this? What specific function to use for this?

Answer (score 1):

For simulation:

- Convert your image to RGB hex file using MATLAB.
- Input this hex file using readmemh in verilog.

[Example](http://www.fpga4student.com/2016/11/image-processing-on-fpga-verilog.html?m=1)

Answer (score 0):

There are two general techniques here:  the simplest method would be to convert the image to something that can be read in directly by the simulator, usually a hex file or binary file of just the pixel data.  This would involve a pre-processing step, probably with some sort of scripting language (python, matlab, etc.), to read in the image and write out the intermediate format.  However, the bitmap file format is relatively simple, so it is also possible to write verilog testbench code that will interpret the bitmap file format directly and extract the pixel data. This would require more verilog code to implement, but it would eliminate the pre-processing step.  It would also be possible to do both of these in reverse, either writing out the intermediate format and then converting or writing out a bitmap directly.

Another thing to consider is using a simpler image format, such as PPM.  This format can be exported by many image editors and may be easier to parse in verilog.